# How to convert a Vue page to a vector-based PDF on the client-side

Tags: vue.js, pdf, html-pdf, vue-pdf

I want to convert an HTML page written with Vue.js to a vector-based PDF client-side. I understand there are solutions in the backend, however, in my case I specifically want client-side. I have very complex Vue components and styling which I would like to print to pdf. I tried multiple approaches and I could not find a solution.

Here is what I tried: -

1. The easiest way I found is `window.print()`.

*The issue with this approach, is that there is no other way to invoke the download functionality directly without going through the pop-dialog. Another issue I found `window.onafterprint` and `window.onbeforeprint` event listeners don't work on firefox but work in chrome. In firefox, both events fire at the same time. regardless, I do not like the default dialog, I would rather build my own.*

2. I retrieved the HTML and CSS from the DOM using `this.$el.innerHTML`, and `window.getComputedStyle(element)` and saved them to a variable, then converted to blob and downloaded it with javascript.

*this solution worked, however only in DEV build, since I bundle my app with Vite, the computed styles don't render on the DOM as I expected when in Production build; which I believe is due to the way Vite bundles CSS for optimization. Therefore the result will only be HTML with no styling.*

3. I used the popular [vue-html2pdf](https://github.com/kempsteven/vue-html2pdf) library and it is straightforward.

*the issue with this approach is the fact it simply renders HTML and CSS to an image the saves as a pdf, therefore the output will be an image-based-pdf. which is not my preferred kind of pdf.*

I cannot find any library that takes in HTML and CSS and covert to a Vector-based pdf on the client-side.

Comment: Hi @Omar Have you found something related to vector pdf in vuejs. I have similar functionality.
Please share If you found something